# Uploading Image into Realtime Database Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I am building app that asks User(Visitor) to: upload image, name, ic, phone number, visit reason, date, time and ticket generated.

For now all data inserting into Realtime database successfully except image. User can choose the image and upload it into Firebase Storage successfully but I cant pass that image among the User data which is in Realtime Database.

When user clicks "send request" button, all other data (name, ic, phone number...) uploading into realtime db and image uploads into storage. But I couldnt implement it to pass the image into Realtime Database.

And I couldnt use StartActivityForResult method thats why didnt use

The uploaded image should be among those data as visitor Image, which under visitor, ticket
[image: The uploaded image should be among those data, which under visitor, ticket]

```
public class ActivityRequestVisit extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://mydblinksampleforstackoverflowpostq.com");

    ImageView imageView;

    FirebaseStorage storage;

    Uri imageUri;

    Button SubmitRequestBtn;

    DatePickerDialog pickerDate;

    TextView ticketGenerated;
    Button btnGenerateTicket;


    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_request_visit);

        SubmitRequestBtn = findViewById(R.id.SubmitRequestBtnId);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.VisitorImageId);

        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mGetContent.launch("image/*");

            }
        });


        //ticket generator starts here
        ticketGenerated = findViewById(R.id.GeneratedVisitorTicketId);
        btnGenerateTicket = findViewById(R.id.GenerateTicketBtnId);


        btnGenerateTicket.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Random random = new Random();
                int generatedTicket = random.nextInt(9999999);
                ticketGenerated.setText(Integer.toString(generatedTicket));
            }
        });
        //ticket generator ends here

        Toast.makeText(ActivityRequestVisit.this,"Send your Request Visit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        final EditText VisitorName = findViewById(R.id.VisitorNameId);
        final EditText VisitorIC = findViewById(R.id.VisitorICId);
        final EditText VisitorPhone = findViewById(R.id.VisitorPhoneId);
        final EditText VisitReason = findViewById(R.id.VisitReasonId);
        final EditText VisitDate = findViewById(R.id.VisitDateId);
        final EditText VisitTime = findViewById(R.id.VisitTimeId);
        final EditText VisitorTicket = findViewById(R.id.VisitorTicketId);

        //date n time picker starts here

        //date picker
        VisitDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"));
                int chosenDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int chosenMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int chosenYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                //DatePicker dialog
                pickerDate = new DatePickerDialog(ActivityRequestVisit.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                        VisitDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
                    }
                }, chosenYear, chosenMonth, chosenDay);

                pickerDate.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
                pickerDate.show();
            }
        });


        //time picker
        VisitTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int chosenHour;
            int chosenMinute;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
                        ActivityRequestVisit.this,
                        android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                                chosenHour = hourOfDay;
                                chosenMinute = minute;
                                //store time into string
                                String time = chosenHour + ":" + chosenMinute;

                                //Initialize 24 h time format
                                SimpleDateFormat f24Hours = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                        "HH:mm"
                                );
                                try {
                                    Date date = f24Hours.parse(time);
                                    //Initialize 12 h time format
                                    SimpleDateFormat f12Hours = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                            "hh:mm aa"
                                    );
                                    //Set selected time on text view
                                    VisitTime.setText(f12Hours.format(date));
                                } catch (ParseException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        },12,0, false
                );
                timePickerDialog.updateTime(chosenHour,chosenMinute);
                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });


//date n time picker ends here

        final Button SubmitRequestBtn = findViewById(R.id.SubmitRequestBtnId);
        SubmitRequestBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                uploadImage();

//Obtain entered data
                final String name = VisitorName.getText().toString();
                final String ic = VisitorIC.getText().toString();
                final String phone = VisitorPhone.getText().toString();
                final String reason = VisitReason.getText().toString();
                final String dateV = VisitDate.getText().toString();
                final String timeV = VisitTime.getText().toString();
                final String ticket = VisitorTicket.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRequestVisit.this,"Please enter your name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    VisitorName.setError("Name is required!");
                    VisitorName.requestFocus();
                } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(ic)) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRequestVisit.this,"Please enter your IC", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    VisitorIC.setError("IC is required!");
                    VisitorIC.requestFocus();
                } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRequestVisit.this,"Please enter your phone number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    VisitorPhone.setError("Phone number is required!");
                    VisitorPhone.requestFocus();
                } else if (phone.length() != 10) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRequestVisit.this,"Please re-enter your phone number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    VisitorPhone.setError("Please enter valid phone number!");
                    VisitorPhone.requestFocus();
                } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(reason)) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRequestVisit.this, "Please enter your visit reason", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    VisitReason.setError("Visit reason is required!");
                    VisitReason.requestFocus();
                } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(dateV)) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRequestVisit.this, "Please enter date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    VisitDate.setError("Date is required!");
                    VisitDate.requestFocus();
                } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(timeV)) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRequestVisit.this, "Please enter time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    VisitTime.setError("Time is required!");
                    VisitTime.requestFocus();
                }else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(ticket)) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRequestVisit.this, "Please enter ticket number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    VisitorTicket.setError("Time is required!");
                    VisitorTicket.requestFocus();
                } else {

                    databaseReference.child("visitors").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                            if(snapshot.hasChild(ticket)){
                                //check for unique ticket number
                                Toast.makeText(ActivityRequestVisit.this,"Please Generate Other Ticket Number Cuz this one is exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                //sending data to firebase realtime db
                                //used ticket number as unique identity and other data comes under it




                                databaseReference.child("visitors").child(ticket).child("visitor name").setValue(name);
                                databaseReference.child("visitors").child(ticket).child("visitor ic").setValue(ic);
                                databaseReference.child("visitors").child(ticket).child("visitor phone").setValue(phone);
                                databaseReference.child("visitors").child(ticket).child("visit reason").setValue(reason);
                                databaseReference.child("visitors").child(ticket).child("visit date").setValue(dateV);
                                databaseReference.child("visitors").child(ticket).child("visit time").setValue(timeV);

                                Toast.makeText(ActivityRequestVisit.this,"Request Sent Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                finish();
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });

                }


            }

        });

    }
    //upload image into storage functions starts here
    private void uploadImage() {

        if (imageUri != null) {
            StorageReference reference = storage.getReference().child("images/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());


            reference.putFile(imageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(ActivityRequestVisit.this,"Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ActivityRequestVisit.this,task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            });
        }


    }
    ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(Uri result) {
                    if (result != null) {
                        imageView.setImageURI(result);
                        imageUri = result;
                    }
                }
            });

    //upload image into storage functions ends here

}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Just upload the image to a firebase Storage and save its url in realtime database

Comment: The User needs to upload the image inside the App. I mean each user uploads images with their other credentials. Not manually ONE image to be uploaded into Firebase Storage

Comment: @TheAch create an intent (StartActivityforResult) to upload images so users can first upload their images on firebase Storage. After uploading, generate the image path with user Auth then pass it to the Realtime database. Only each user can see only their images.